# separating a notepad file into multiple files

Tags: windows, notepad

I have very minimum, essentially no programming knowledge besides an introductory python course at my univeristy so I apologize if this question is worded oddly. In my current internship one of my tasks include opening a notepad which includes a header, followed by multiple statments with unique id's, and then copying and pasting the header and one of the statments into a new notepad for each of the id's, and renaming the file based on which id was used.

I am unfamiliar with doing any sort of programing in notepad so my question is, is this possible to automate and make it a less manual task of copying and pasting. I have basic knowledge of python file input & output, could that be applied here?

Comment: Yes, Python or any other programming language can do this. . Stack overflow typically works best if you do some research, hit a wall and then share what specific issues you ran into (along with any code you wrote), so I'd recommend you dive in, break down your problem in multiple steps and see how far you can get. Good luck on your journey!

Comment: Is your file a CSV-like file? That is to say, does it look [like this](https://i.imgur.com/5Epjxs3.png) (first row is the header, and it contains **columns**, separated by commas, while the other rows contain **values** corresponding to the headers in the first row, and they are also separated by commas)? Can you give us an example of how your file looks like? You can copy / paste a part of it in your question.